# Spaces in Swift's Markup Language

Tags: swift, documentation, markup

Documentation on Swift provides the following code for *spacing* `Example`s in Markup:

```
/*:
  - example: *A simple `for` loop.*\
  This example shows a `for` loop that prints the numbers 1 to 5.\
    \
     `for index in 1...5 {`\
     `   print("index = \(index)")`\
     `}`}
 */
```

In rendered Markup no spaces appear:

[image]

How do you put spaces in code snippets, especially examples with custom `callouts()`, in Markup?

Comment: @tktsubota, I tried but with triple back ticks. Unfortunately these do not help with custom `callouts()`.

Comment: Do you use the Markup for Playgrounds or Code documentation?

Comment: @ronatory The code is in a Playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to show the spaces in your code example try to do it like that regarding to your example:

```
/*:
A simple for loop.\
This example shows a for loop that prints the numbers 1 to 5.

    for index in 1...5 {
        print("index = \(index)")
    }
*/
```

**Result looks in Rendered Markup like this (the spaces appear in the code block):**
[image]

**Edit after comment:**

The only way I found out, so that your first two lines of Markup are also inside of the example and also to simulate spaces is to use this code (in the line of the print, first two backquotes and between them one space, then after that eight spaces until the opening backquote of the print):

```
/*:
- example: *A simple `for` loop.*\
This example shows a `for` loop that prints the numbers 1 to 5.\
\
`for index in 1...5 {`\
` `        `print("index = \(index)")`\
`}`}
*/
```

**This results to:**

[image]

Comment: If you compare the sidebar in your image to that of mine, you will notice that the first two lines of Markup are outside of the example. Your code does not make a call to `callout()`.

Comment: Updated the answer, but I don't really get what you mean by making a call to `callout()`